# VM got 10.0.x.x address instead of 192.168.x.x address?

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

I've searched the [similar question](https://superuser.com/questions/398478/change-virtualbox-dhcp-to-issue-192-168-x-x-adresses-instead-of-10-0-x-x-adresse) (and prepared to be downvoted too).
I'm new to virtualbox, and I have Ubuntu-server-VM (with guest addition installed) run on my Windows-10-Host using VirtualBox-5.2.16 (extension pack installed).
I need to `ssh` using `putty` **from host to VM**
Below is my setting in Host Network Manager setting, VM network setting, all done follow internet guide, but the VM still got IP in `10.0.2.15` instead of `192.168.56.x`. So I can't connect to VM.
What did I do wrong? And how can I fix it? 
Many thanks!

[image: Host Network Manager config]
[image: VM IP]
[image: VM network setting - adapter 1]
[image: VM network setting - adapter 2]
[image: my ipconfig and ping result]

Comment: Change adapter #1 to bridged network, then VM will pick IP address from host's network and you would be able to connect to it. As of now you using NATed VM

Comment: @Alex: well, now my VM got IP in `10.133.78.x` which is come from my company's DCHP, this is not good for me because my company doesn't allow VM to join LAN network.

Comment: `10.0.2.15` would indicate there is a router with DHCP enabled on the network. Likewise, your machine is being assigned a public IP address.  Your screenshot indicates your VM has two network adapters.  Is there a reason?

Comment: @Luke Switch then back to NAT on adapter #1 if company doesn't allows to join network and check in ubuntu content of `/etc/network`, it should be default to DHCP. this way ubuntu would pick IP address from 192.168.56.0/24 IP addresses range that you can access from host or better set static IP address in ubuntu to some 192.168.56.100

Comment: @Luke I meant to some static IP below 192.168.56.100

Comment: @Ramhound that's not the reason, my VM got stuck with error `mtu 1500 qdisc noop state down group default qlen 1000`

Comment: @Alex thanks for comments, I got my problem solved below, please check my own answer. Moreover, in `/etc/network` there are 6 file, I'm noob with linux, which one are you mentioning?

Comment: @Luke `/etc/network/interfaces` file is a primary place where one can set network related settings. This file also source any files located in the `/etc/network/interfaces.d/*` that must have the same directives as in the `/etc/network/interfaces`. There should be a line  `allow-hotplug NameOfYourInterface` that automatically UP interface. Another line is `iface NameOfYourInterface inet dhcp` that tells ubuntu to use DHCP to get IP address

Comment: @Luke - You avoided my question altogether.  I wasn't saying it was the cause, I was trying to understand, the reason you had two adapters configured.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for comments,
As my company doesn't allow me to use IP from their DCHP, I've revert the Adapter 1 to `NAT`, then set Adapter 2 to `Host Only network`, after that, I check the ip with `ip addr` and notice that I got the error `mtu 1500 qdisc noop state down group default qlen 1000`, then I followed Google and find out 2 command to solve it: 

`sudo ip link set dev eth0 up
sudo dhclient -v eth0`

[Reference Link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/234029/how-do-i-fix-debian-that-refuses-to-connect-to-the-internet-in-virtualbox)

Comment: It is strange if it works because according to your screenshots, the name of your network adapter in Ubuntu is `enp0s3`, not a `eth0`

Answer (score 0):

I am working on a macOS Catalina version 10.15.7 as a host of a Virtual Box  VM:Centos 7. Same problem . The bridge adapter did not make a difference, but only with an adapter *Attached to : Host-only Adapter*  and *Name :vboxnet0*  .
*vboxnet0* can be created from File > Host Network Manager > Create.
It will work with DHCP enabled or disabled and also with manual or authomatically adapter configuration

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).