# libvirt/qemu network guest dhclient 10.0.2.15 instead of 192.168.122.2

Tags: virtualization, dhcp, libvirt

On the redhat host, `virbr0` is up and libvirt's network is configured as `nat` for `192.168.122.2-254` (and recently added rule specifically to assign `192.168.122.2`). but `dhclient` with the ubuntu VM gets `10.0.2.15` instead.

This maybe a duplicate of [vm-got-10-0-x-x](https://superuser.com/questions/1353130/vm-got-10-0-x-x-address-instead-of-192-168-x-x-address) or [change-virtualbox-dhcp-to-issue-192-168-x-x](https://superuser.com/questions/398478/change-virtualbox-dhcp-to-issue-192-168-x-x-adresses-instead-of-10-0-x-x-adresse), but I don't know how to translate `VBoxManage modifyvm  "NameOfVM" --natnet1 "192.168/16"` to qemu/virsh and I think the config is already correctly NAT

```
brctl show
 bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
 virbr0          8000.52540024cafa       yes             virbr0-nic


ip addr show virbr0|grep inet
 inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0

virsh list --all
 Id    Name                           State
 ---------------------------------------------------
 2     fw-core                        running

sudo virsh net-dumpxml default

<network>
  <name>default</name>
  <uuid>b270007c-ada2-4c16-9b34-3abecc1c4b94</uuid>
  <forward mode='nat'>
    <nat>
      <port start='1024' end='65535'/>
    </nat>
  </forward>
  <bridge name='virbr0' stp='on' delay='0'/>
  <mac address='52:54:00:24:ca:fa'/>
  <ip address='192.168.122.1' netmask='255.255.255.0'>
    <dhcp>
      <range start='192.168.122.2' end='192.168.122.254'/>
      <host mac='52:54:00:6d:e4:ae' name='fw-core' ip='192.168.122.2'/>
    </dhcp>
  </ip>
</network>
```

I can connect from the host to the guest using `virsh console fw-core` but not `ssh 10.0.2.15`

The VM skips right over the bridge and gets an IP from the enterprise network(?). `dhclient` gets the ip from `10.0.2.2` instead of `192.168.122.1`. And I cannot connect to the VM using it's assigned IP from the host.

```
sudo dhclient -v ens3 

Listening on LPF/ens3/52:54:00:6d:e4:ae
Sending on   LPF/ens3/52:54:00:6d:e4:ae
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on ens3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xf27cb27a)
DHCPOFFER of 10.0.2.15 from 10.0.2.2
DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.2.15 on ens3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0x7ab27cf2)
DHCPACK of 10.0.2.15 from 10.0.2.2 (xid=0xf27cb27a)
bound to 10.0.2.15 -- renewal in 32873 seconds.
```

and fails trying to force the `192.168.122.1` as the dhcp server address

```
sudo dhclient -v ens3 -s 192.168.122.1
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.4.1
Copyright 2004-2018 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/ens3/52:54:00:6d:e4:ae
Sending on   LPF/ens3/52:54:00:6d:e4:ae
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPREQUEST for 10.0.2.15 on ens3 to 192.168.122.1 port 67 (xid=0x1557fbe4)
DHCPREQU
```

For what it's worth, the guest VM can connect to the outside world and to the host ssh server

```
curl -s google.com|sed 1q
    <HTML><HEAD><meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">

sleep 1 | telnet 192.168.122.1 22
     Trying 192.168.122.1...
     Connected to 192.168.122.1.
     Escape character is '^]'.
     SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
     Connection closed by foreign host
```

and ssh is running in the VM

```
sleep 1|telnet localhost 22
 Trying 127.0.0.1...
 Connected to localhost.
 Escape character is '^]'.
 SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3ubuntu0.4
 Connection closed by foreign host.
```

My other thought is a firewall issue on the host. But I've added the bridge as an internal zone

```
sudo firewall-cmd --zone=internal --list-all
 internal (active)
  target: default
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: virbr0
  sources: 
  services: dhcp dhcpv6-client mdns samba-client ssh
  ports: 67/tcp 67/udp
  protocols: 
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules:
```

EDIT: all interfaces on host

```
 ip addr

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0a:6c:8e:88:52:62 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:d1:18:54 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.48.86.33/24 brd 10.48.86.255 scope global noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::310c:bed0:9e4f:f53d/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: eno2: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 3c:ec:ef:d1:18:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
13: virbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:24:ca:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
14: virbr0-nic: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast master virbr0 state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 52:54:00:24:ca:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff


brctl show
bridge name     bridge id               STP enabled     interfaces
virbr0          8000.52540024cafa       yes             virbr0-nic
```

Edit 2: VM created like

```
virt-install --name core --ram $((1024*4)) --file=fw-core.img --file=ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso
```

Comment: Apparently you enslaved a physical NIC to virbr0? Better include full `ip a` output in your post.

Comment: Ah, I think I know what's the problem here. It seems that somehow your VM is created with a qemu "slirp" nic. Usually that shouldn't happen if you created it with virt-manager or so. But perhaps you messed with the xml or imported a qemu command line?

Comment: at least not intentionally. I used `virt-install` I have now messed with net-edit whole lot, but not before running into networking problems

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not really familiar with libvirt. Try to see if you have some [`user` type interface](https://libvirt.org/formatdomain.html#userspace-slirp-or-passt-connection) in the xml and remove it if so. (And make sure there's a `network` type one.)

Answer (score 0):

Debug credit to Tom Yan in the comments of the question: Qemu is using slirp usermode networking because I created and ran from an unprivileged user. Migrating the VM from `qemu:///session` to `qemu:///server` and updating the guest network config got the guest to `192.168.122.2` via dhcpc.

This is obvious in hindsight. `virsh net-list --all` was empty but `sudo virsh net-list --all` showed `default` nat setup.

To help reduce the confusion, I added to `~/.config/libvirt/libvirt.conf`

```
uri_default = "qemu:///system"
```

Migration looked like

```
virsh -c qemu:///session dumpxml fw-core > fw-core.xml
virsh -c qemu:///session shutdown fw-core
virsh -c qemu:///session undefine fw-core
sudo virsh -c qemu:///system define fw-core.xml
```

and changed the network to `nat` (relevant section of `fw-core.xml`):

```
  <interface type='network'>
      <mac address='52:54:00:6d:e4:ae'/>
      <source network='default' bridge='virbr0'/>
      <target dev='vnet0'/>
      <model type='virtio'/>
      <alias name='net0'/>
      <address type='pci' domain='0x0000' bus='0x00' slot='0x03' function='0x0'/>
    </interface>
```

Here are screenshots of

- `git difftool --tool=vimdiff` highlighting change from interface type=user to type=network and
- `virt-manager` showing the same thing: "virtual hardware details" of "NIC" now set to  "Virtual network 'default'"

[image: vimdiff of xmldump]
[image: vit-manager]